# PHPExcel PDF Library has not been defined

Tags: php, phpexcel

For the life of me I cannot get PHPExcel to see my PDF library.

Here is what I currently have:

```
$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_MPDF;
  $rendererLibrary = 'mPDF5.4';
  $rendererLibraryPath = dirname(__FILE__).'/mpdf/' . $rendererLibrary;

  //  Here's the magic: you __tell__ PHPExcel what rendering engine to use
  //  and where the library is located in your filesystem
  if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer(
      $rendererName,
      $rendererLibraryPath
      )) {
      die(
          'Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .
          PHP_EOL .
          ' as appropriate for your directory structure'
      );
  }

  $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_PDF($objPHPExcel);
  $objWriter->save("test.pdf");
```

My "mpdf" folder is located in the root of this project folder and so is my  relevant php file.

But in the browser I keep seeing:

> Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values as
>   appropriate for your directory structure

I have read the relevant section of the [documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/10-Reading-and-Writing.md) but I don't understand why my php script cannot see my pdf library.

Comment: I see you copied this more or less from the documentation. What directory contents are at `/thiscurrentpath/mpdf/mPDF5.4`? Is that a directory or a file? Can you post the output from `ls -l /thiscurrentpath/mpdf/`, assuming you are on a unix-like system with `ls`

Comment: Permissions are: `drwxrwxr-x 14 www-data www-data 4096 Feb 13 22:56 mpdf5.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHPExcel code only makes two checks here: that a folder called `dirname(__FILE__).'/mpdf/mPDF5.4` exists (using a [file_exists()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) call); and that it is readable (using [is_readable()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php)).... and one or other of those checks is failing.

Check permissions for that folder

Comment: If I do `ls -al` within /mpdf/ I get this: `drwxrwxr-x 14 www-data www-data 4096 Feb 13 22:56 mpdf5.4`

Comment: Well you can check the PHPExcel code for yourself, it's not doing anything clever.... are you running PHP in safe mode, or with suhosin, or in any way that could restrict file_exists() or is_readable() from accessing that folder?

Comment: Thanks, it was a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found changing the 'die' to 'echo' helped find the issue I was having with the $rendererLibraryPath

Comment: What do you mean?